# Need help unformatting text

Tags: html, regex, formatting

I am currently programming a Visual C# service to receive emails from various sources then I take certain info and organize it in a database using Regex to retrieve the deferent cell values (such as header, body, problem, cost, etc.etc.).

My problem is that I am currently using a Hotmail account to email the service which the service then extracts data and writes it to a csv file; however this is all going fine an dandy except for the fact that the text is formated so when there is a "\n" or something of the sort, the program decides to not input the data that follows that into the cell.

For instance, if I emailed this:

Cost:$1000.00

Body:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate mattis dolor, a dapibus turpis lacinia mollis. Fusce in enim nulla, sit amet gravida dolor. Suspendisse at nisi velit, vel ornare odio. Integer metus justo, imperdiet et pellentesque in, facilisis dignissim metus. Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus purus nisl, hendrerit sit amet rutrum eu, euismod in felis. Maecenas blandit, metus ac eleifend vulputate, nibh ligula mollis mi, non malesuada nunc tellus ac risus. In at rutrum elit. Proin metus sem, ullamcorper ut rhoncus sed, semper nec tellus. Maecenas adipiscing nisl nec elit egestas vel bibendum justo vehicula.

Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam fermentum enim in magna consequat a lacinia felis iaculis. Ut odio justo, consectetur nec cursus eu, dignissim non sapien. Duis tincidunt fringilla aliquet. Vivamus elementum lobortis massa vel posuere. Aenean non congue odio. Aenean aliquam elit volutpat tortor tempor pharetra. Mauris non est eu orci ultricies lacinia. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut vitae orci lectus, sit amet convallis nunc. Vivamus feugiat ante at justo auctor at pretium ante congue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed at feugiat odio.

The body cell would look as follows:

```
<span class=3D"ecxecxApple-style-s=
pan" style=3D"font-family:Arial=2C Helvetica=2C sans=3Bfont-size:11px"><p s=
tyle=3D"text-align:justify=3Bfont-size:11px=3Bline-height:14px=3Bmargin-rig=
ht:0px=3Bmargin-bottom:14px=3Bmargin-left:0px=3Bpadding-top:0px=3Bpadding-r=
ight:0px=3Bpadding-bottom:0px=3Bpadding-left:0px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame=
t=2C consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent in augue nec justo tempor varius=
 eu et tellus. Nunc id massa tortor=2C ut lobortis sem. Class aptent taciti=
 sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra=2C per inceptos himenaeos. =
Maecenas quis nisl nec quam tristique posuere sed at nibh. Cras fringilla v=
estibulum metus vel porttitor. Cras iaculis=2C erat nec gravida accumsan=2C=
 metus felis vestibulum risus=2C quis venenatis nisl nulla sed diam. Aenean=
 quis viverra velit. Etiam quis massa lectus=2C faucibus facilisis sem. Cur=
abitur non eros tellus. Sed at ligula neque. Donec elementum rhoncus volutp=
at. Curabitur eu accumsan erat. Phasellus auctor odio dolor=2C ut ornare au=
gue. Suspendisse vel est nibh. Vivamus facilisis placerat augue sit amet al=
iquam. Maecenas viverra=2C ipsum a tincidunt elementum=2C arcu tellus rutru=
m ipsum=2C et dignissim urna orci ac mi. Vivamus non odio massa. Nulla cong=
ue massa eu leo pretium non consequat urna molestie.</p><p style=3D"text-al=
ign:justify=3Bfont-size:11px=3Bline-height:14px=3Bmargin-right:0px=3Bmargin=
-bottom:14px=3Bmargin-left:0px=3Bpadding-top:0px=3Bpadding-right:0px=3Bpadd=
ing-bottom:0px=3Bpadding-left:0px">Integer neque odio=2C scelerisque at mol=
estie quis=2C congue sed arcu. Praesent a arcu odio. Donec sollicitudin=2C =
quam vel tincidunt lobortis=2C urna augue cursus lorem=2C in eleifend nunc =
risus nec neque. Donec euismod mauris non nibh blandit sollicitudin. Vivamu=
s sed tincidunt augue. Suspendisse iaculis massa ut tellus rutrum auctor. C=
ras venenatis consequat urna in viverra. Ut blandit imperdiet dolor non sce=
lerisque. Suspendisse potenti. Sed vitae lacus ac odio euismod tempus. Aene=
an ut sem odio. Curabitur auctor purus a diam iaculis facilisis. Integer mo=
lestie commodo mauris a imperdiet. Nunc aliquet tempus orci sit amet viverr=
a.</p><p style=3D"text-align:justify=3Bfont-size:11px=3Bline-height:14px=3B=
margin-right:0px=3Bmargin-bottom:14px=3Bmargin-left:0px=3Bpadding-top:0px=
=3Bpadding-right:0px=3Bpadding-bottom:0px=3Bpadding-left:0px">Morbi ultrici=
es fermentum magna=2C et ultricies urna convallis non. Aenean nibh felis=2C=
 faucibus et pellentesque ultrices=2C accumsan a ligula. Aliquam vulputate =
nisi vitae mi pretium et pretium nulla aliquet. Nam egestas diam vel elit c=
ommodo fermentum. Aenean venenatis bibendum tellus=2C eget scelerisque risu=
s consequat ut. In porta interdum eleifend. Cras laoreet venenatis pulvinar=
.. Praesent ultricies tristique lorem=2C quis interdum arcu scelerisque nec.=
 Quisque arcu tellus=2C consectetur vel mattis nec=2C feugiat ac quam. Prae=
sent sit amet fermentum nulla. Nulla lobortis=2C odio vitae elementum aucto=
r=2C libero turpis condimentum mi=2C sed aliquet felis sapien nec tortor. I=
nteger vehicula=2C neque in egestas accumsan=2C felis metus sagittis nulla=
=2C eu dapibus ligula ipsum ut sapien. Nulla quis urna tortor=2C sed facili=
sis leo. In at metus sed velit venenatis varius. Fusce aliquam mattis enim=
=2C vitae tincidunt sem cursus in.</p><p style=3D"text-align:justify=3Bfont=
-size:11px=3Bline-height:14px=3Bmargin-right:0px=3Bmargin-bottom:14px=3Bmar=
gin-left:0px=3Bpadding-top:0px=3Bpadding-right:0px=3Bpadding-bottom:0px=3Bp=
adding-left:0px">Proin tincidunt ligula at ligula bibendum vitae condimentu=
m nunc congue. Curabitur ac magna nibh=2C vel accumsan nisl. Duis nec eros =
et purus vestibulum tincidunt at sit amet libero. Donec eu nibh eros. Pelle=
ntesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac tu=
rpis egestas. Donec accumsan=2C tellus at luctus faucibus=2C est nibh sempe=
r diam=2C vitae adipiscing lorem tellus vel nulla. Donec eget ipsum ut lore=
m tristique ultricies. Aliquam sem diam=2C semper sit amet volutpat pretium=
=2C lobortis et eros. Sed vel iaculis metus. Phasellus malesuada elementum =
porta.</p><p style=3D"text-align:justify=3Bfont-size:11px=3Bline-height:14p=
x=3Bmargin-right:0px=3Bmargin-bottom:14px=3Bmargin-left:0px=3Bpadding-top:0=
px=3Bpadding-right:0px=3Bpadding-bottom:0px=3Bpadding-left:0px">Fusce tinci=
dunt dignissim massa quis dapibus. Sed aliquet consequat orci=2C eu cursus =
libero dapibus vitae. Pellentesque at felis felis=2C vitae condimentum libe=
ro. Vivamus eros erat=2C elementum et tristique vitae=2C mattis et neque. P=
raesent bibendum leo ac tortor congue id mollis libero ornare. Pellentesque=
 adipiscing accumsan mi=2C a bibendum purus dignissim id. Cum sociis natoqu=
e penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes=2C nascetur ridiculus mus. Morb=
i mollis nisi in nibh cursus facilisis. Ut eu quam dolor=2C sit amet congue=
 orci. Aliquam quam dolor=2C viverra vitae varius sed=2C molestie et quam. =
Suspendisse purus mauris=2C fermentum condimentum pharetra at=2C molestie a=
 nunc. Nam rhoncus euismod venenatis. Nam pellentesque quam ac ipsum volutp=
at a eleifend odio imperdiet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torque=
nt per conubia nostra=2C per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla in nunc magna. Lorem=
 ipsum dolor sit amet=2C consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pretium tincidu=
nt gravida.</p></span>
```

As you can tell I need a way to get rid of all that html junk and make it readable again. Is there anyway to do this with Regex? Or an easier way if possible.

Cheers

Comment: Watch out. HTML is NOT a regular language, so using RegExp can sometimes lead to problems.

That being said, If you have some specific formats in your email, you could somehow replace some tags to other values (like <BR/> to "\n")

Comment: What exactly do you want to get rid of. THe `=2C` characters or all of the HTML?

Comment: I'm currenly using this function:

        private string Deformat(string text)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(text, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
        }

Problem is, I still have things like =2C (instead of ',') and no line breaks or paragraph formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing `<[^>]+>` with `\n` (or whatever your platform's newline character is)?

This will replace each tag with a newline (as long as your tags never contain a `>` inside an attribute - this is one of the risks when trying to parse HTML with regexes).

Then, replace `=(2C|\n)` with nothing.

Comment: On question though, Now I appear to have multiple line breaks in between paragraphs (I'm guessing because there where many tags. Is there anyway to merge multiple line breaks into one?

Comment: Great to hear it. As for the multiple line breaks, you could search for `\n{2,}` and replace those with `\n`.